# unity 2d auto shadow caster 2d at wall-closed tilemap

Tags: 2d

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0F8boyFinOk&t=12s

While making a roguelike game with Unity2d, I applied an automatic shadow generator to a randomly generated tilemap from the video above. But it doesn't work for tilemaps that are closed due to using the CompositeCollider2d's Path. How do I solve it?

[Generated Shadow Shape(outer)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qElMY.png)

[Generated Shadow Shape(inner)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfJJg.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I used this code : https://github.com/SeksitSeeton/Auto-add-Shadow-Caster-2D-on-TileMap/blob/main/Assets/ShadowCaster2DTileMap.cs

Comment: I solved it! I solved it by creating AutoShadowClosedTilemap.cs that connects two Path Vertices to one Path Vertices. Here's the code for those who are having the same problem: https://pastebin.com/DJuXPbrz

Answer (score 0):

Solved with this code:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal;
using System.Collections.Generic;
 
[RequireComponent(typeof(CompositeCollider2D))]
public class AutoShadowClosedTilemap : MonoBehaviour
{
 
    [Space]
    [SerializeField]
    private bool selfShadows = true;
 
    private CompositeCollider2D tilemapCollider;
    private List<Vector2> unionVertices = new();
 
 
    static readonly FieldInfo meshField = typeof(ShadowCaster2D).GetField("m_Mesh", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    static readonly FieldInfo shapePathField = typeof(ShadowCaster2D).GetField("m_ShapePath", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    static readonly MethodInfo generateShadowMeshMethod = typeof(ShadowCaster2D)
            .Assembly
            .GetType("UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal.ShadowUtility")
            .GetMethod("GenerateShadowMesh", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
 
    [ContextMenu("Generate")]
    public void Generate()
    {
        tilemapCollider = GetComponent<CompositeCollider2D>();
 
        if(tilemapCollider.pathCount != 2) {
            print("Shadow must be used in one closed tiles. Please erase the other tiles to other Tilemap.");
            return;
        }
 
        unionVertices.Clear();
        DestroyAllChildren();
 
 
        Vector2[] pathVertices = new Vector2[tilemapCollider.GetPathPointCount(0)];
        tilemapCollider.GetPath(0, unionVertices);
        tilemapCollider.GetPath(1, pathVertices);
 
        var index = 0;
        var endPath = unionVertices[unionVertices.Count - 1];
        var length = Vector2.Distance(pathVertices[0], endPath);
 
        for(var i = 1; i < pathVertices.Length; i++) {
            var path = pathVertices[i];
            var curLen = Vector2.Distance(endPath, path);
            if(curLen < length) {
                length = curLen;
                index = i;
            }
        }
 
        for(var i = 0; i < pathVertices.Length; i++) {
            var path = pathVertices[(i + index) % pathVertices.Length];
            unionVertices.Add(path);
        }
 
        for(var i = 0; i < unionVertices.Count; i++) {
            var cur = unionVertices[i];
            var next = unionVertices[(i + 1) % unionVertices.Count];
 
            Debug.DrawLine(cur, cur + (next - cur) * 0.5f, Color.red);
        }
        
        var shadowCaster = new GameObject("ShadowCaster");
        shadowCaster.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
        shadowCaster.transform.position = Vector3.zero;
        ShadowCaster2D shadowCasterComponent = shadowCaster.AddComponent<ShadowCaster2D>();
        shadowCasterComponent.selfShadows = this.selfShadows;
 
        var testPath = new Vector3[unionVertices.Count];
        var j = 0;
        foreach (var path in unionVertices)
        {
            testPath[j++] = path;
        }
 
        shapePathField.SetValue(shadowCasterComponent, testPath);
        meshField.SetValue(shadowCasterComponent, new Mesh());
        generateShadowMeshMethod.Invoke(shadowCasterComponent, new object[] { meshField.GetValue(shadowCasterComponent), shapePathField.GetValue(shadowCasterComponent) });
 
        Debug.Log("Shadow Generated");
 
    }
    public void DestroyAllChildren()
    {
 
        var tempList = transform.Cast<Transform>().ToList();
        foreach (var child in tempList)
        {
            DestroyImmediate(child.gameObject);
        }
 
    }
 
}
```